# Need to display a value in string format in CodeIgniter view

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am trying to display a value `$raw` which is in an array format to a textbox in a CodeIgniter view

This is the function I am using in my controller:

```
public function pricing($raw='array')
{
    if ($raw === 'array')
    {
        return $this->result_array();
    }
}
```

I tried this but still getting `message:array to string conversion`

I am using `$raw` in my view 'add_calendar.php':`

```
<?php echo(['name'=>'tohr','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter total hire rate','value'=>'$raw'])?>
```

Comment: Did you tried with json_encode ??

Comment: how do i try with json_encode

Comment: what is in `$raw`?

Comment: if($diff->m){$month=$diff->m*$pricing['month'];}

    if($diff->d){
        $days=$diff->d%7;
        $raw=$month+$days*$pricing['day'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not echo an array because echo expects string as its parameter. Since you are trying to echo the values to a textbox you may want to do this.

When you load your view pass `$raw` to your view.

```
$data = array('raw'=>$raw);
$this->load->view('add_calendar', $data);
```

Then in your view use `form_input` to create a textbox.

```
echo form_input(['name'=>'tohr','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter total hire rate','value'=>$raw]);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192911/discussion-on-answer-by-nipun-need-to-display-a-value-in-string-format-in-codeig).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array from the controller to view

`$raw` is a variable don't use single quotes `'` for it

```
$data['record'] = array('name'=>'tohr','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter total hire rate','value'=> $raw);
return $this->load->view('file', $data);
```

View

You can use these values with or without HTML tags

Without HTML tags

```
<?= $name ?> //tohar
<?=  $class ?> //form-control
<?= $raw ?>
```

With HTML tags

```
<td><?= $name ?></td>
<p><?= $name ?></p>
<h3><?= $name ?></h3>
```

Comment: how do i use:<?= $name ?> //tohar
<?=  $class ?> //form-control
<?= $raw ?>  in my view. Can you please be more specific Danish.

Comment: how do i use: <?= $name ?> //tohar
<?=  $class ?> //form-control
<?= $raw ?> in my view

Comment: <?= form_input(['name'=>'tohr','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter total hire rate','value'=>$raw])?>